# Obtener el primer elemento anidado en una matriz de un archivo JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, mongodb

Tengo un archivo JSON alojado en MongoDB y quiero obtener el primer elemento de la matriz de `properties`

```
{
  "_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad6135",
  "election": "local-min-2015",
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5039258.279933322,
              5142586.1579948
            ],
            [
              5039615.847231327,
              5142411.105566747
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "1": {
          "Partido Popular": "50.64"
        },
        "2": {
          "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": "3.22"
        },
        "3": {
          "Unidos Podemos": "1.29"
        },
        "4": {
          "Ciudadanos": "26.18"
        },
        "5": {
          "Vox": "18.45"
        },
        "id": 96918,
        "parent_id": 96916,
        "common_id": "11.01",
        "common_name": "11.01",
        "has_children": true,
        "shape_type_id": 5,
        "shape_type_name": "Majoritarian District",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Majoritarian District: 11.01",
        "Total Voter Turnout (%)": 55.08
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5039258.279933322,
              5142586.1579948
            ],
            [
              5039615.847231327,
              5142411.105566747
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "1": {
          "Partido Popular": "45.64"
        },
        "2": {
          "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": "7.22"
        },
        "3": {
          "Unidos Podemos": "2.29"
        },
        "4": {
          "Ciudadanos": "26.18"
        },
        "5": {
          "Vox": "18.45"
        },
        "id": 96919,
        "parent_id": 96916,
        "common_id": "11.01",
        "common_name": "11.01",
        "has_children": true,
        "shape_type_id": 5,
        "shape_type_name": "Majoritarian District",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Majoritarian District: 11.01",
        "Total Voter Turnout (%)": 55.08
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Me gustaria obtener:

```
"properties": {
        "1": {
          "Partido Popular": "50.64"
        },
        "2": {
          "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": "3.22"
        },
        "3": {
          "Unidos Podemos": "1.29"
        },
        "4": {
          "Ciudadanos": "26.18"
        },
        "5": {
          "Vox": "18.45"
        }
```

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
import pymongo
from bson.son import SON
import json

import os

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

db = client["Richmond"]

collection = db['Collection']

# select the documents where the field features contains the field 0
cursor = collection.find(
    { "election": "local-maj-2017" },
    { "features.0": 1 }#, "type": 0, "election": 0, "_id": 0 } # get the very first item of the features array
)

for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\Mongo>python query_mongdb.py
{'_id': ObjectId('5de9483c65222ef002ad6135'), 'features': [{}, {}]}
```

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas de respuesta?

Comment: @Sr1871 Seguro, me lo acabo de poner.

Comment: Para una consulta de este estilo te sugiero usar un proceso de [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/index.html). En cuanto pueda intentaré darte una respuesta con un ejemplo. Saludos